# opening ViewController raise unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift2

I'm trying to open a new ViewController from my code by using

```
let registrationView = NewOrdoViewController()
self.presentViewController(registrationView, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

my NewOrdoViewController is containing a ScrollView and while opening the new View, my app crash at the following line:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    scrollView.contentSize.height = 2000 <-- it crash here
......
```

with the following error:

```
unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

is there any specific command to instantiate a new ViewController containing a ScrollView ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're opening a generic `NewOrdoViewController`, not the instance that exists in your storyboard. Give your `NewOrdoViewController` a storyboard ID in the interface builder and replace

```
let registrationView = NewOrdoViewController()
```

with

```
let registrationView = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YourStoryboardID") as! NewOrdoViewController
```

Comment: would like to mention that this is not as good of practice as having a segue from one VC to the next, and calling performSegueWithIdentifier though